# How do I use a webcam in ROS?

Tags: ros, camera-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a generic driver for webcams to get images on a ROS topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9511/how-do-i-use-a-webcam-in-ros?/) by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The usb_cam package works great for my Logitech camera http://www.ros.org/wiki/usb_cam. The ROS sensors page gives an overview of available drivers http://www.ros.org/wiki/Sensors#Cameras

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on 2015-06-30**:
I am using logitech USB camera, when i run the node the following error is showing up, how can i fix it?

[ERROR] [1435660270.040129611]: outbuf size mismatch.  pic_size: 604160 bufsize: 614400

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2015-10-06**:
What logitech webcam are you using?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a [community wiki page](http://answers.ros.org/question/57/what-driver-should-i-use-for-my-usb-camera) with a table of standard USB camera drivers. It lists the drivers by feature, underlying driver, download link and license.

---

Originally posted by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) with karma: 438 on 2011-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As suggested USB_CAM is a package for USB cameras,but to access the integrated webcams use the package GSCAM.

---

Originally posted by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) with karma: 174 on 2012-01-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1